# Cosine Similarity on large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, cosine-similarity

I am trying to compute cosine distance between all pairs of a large matrix (3m x 2048) and extract the top30 similar vectors using pytorch.
the following is my code which works fine but it take about 30 sec for each iteration which is too long for 3 million word vectors.
Any idea to speed it up ?

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import gc



sym_dict={}
tmp_list=[]

tot_dict=torch.load('xbx.pt')


all_tensors = torch.cat([v.unsqueeze(0) for k,v in tot_dict.items()], dim=0)
token_list= [i for i in tot_dict.keys()]

del tot_dict
gc.collect()



for counter ,value in tqdm(enumerate(token_list)):


  uniq_vec=torch.unsqueeze(all_tensors[counter],dim=0)

  dist = 1 - F.cosine_similarity(uniq_vec,all_tensors)
  index_sorted = torch.argsort(dist)


  roll_me=index_sorted[:30].cpu().numpy().tolist()

  for ind in roll_me:
    tmp_list.append(token_list[ind])
  sym_dict.update({value:tmp_list})
  tmp_list=[]



#save .pt file
torch.save(sym_dict,'sym_dict.pt')
```

Comment: Few details like shapes of tensors, what each loop is trying to do etc. would make it easier to answer for us

Comment: Each tensor is of shape (1x2048) representing a word embedding vector. The whole matrix is made up 3 million word vectors so its shape is (3M x 2048). Each loop compares one vector against the whole matrix to find the top30 nearest vectors using cosine distance. Each of 3M word vectors should be compared this way so that we can find a top30 list for each word

Answer (score 0):

Would directly finding pairwise distances between the two matrices work? Here's the code:

```
def pairwise_dist(x, y,p=2, eps=1e-6):
    x_a  =x[..., None, :, :]
    y_a  =y[...,None,:]
    dist = torch.pow(torch.abs((x_a - y_a) + eps), p).sum(dim=-1, keepdim=True).squeeze(2)
    return torch.pow(dist, 1/p)

t1 = torch.rand(3, 10)
t2 = torch.rand(4,10)
dist = pairwise_dist(t1,t2, eps=0)
print(dist)
```

`dist` is of shape `4 x 3` where each row represents distance of all vectors of `t1` with a vector of `t2`.

Note that pairwise distance between two vectors here is exactly equivalent to Pytorch's `F. pairwise_distance`.

Comment: It consumes all memory even with small sizes of matrix (tested 10,000 word vectors)